How to show more items in DatePicker Android?
I have a date picker:
<DatePicker
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

and it looks like this:
result I get
I am trying to make next two and previus two dates visible.
It shoudl look like this:
wanted result

I had to achieve the same effect a long time ago, and I used this WheelView at that time.
There is an attribute itemVisibleNum which meets the requirement.

I am new with gitHub.
How can I import the WheelView into my project, there is no implementation?
